# Android Async HTTP library: How to store value from onSuccess method?

Tags: java, scope, android-async-http

I need to store value from `onSuccess` method of `getJobs` GET request to `jobs` variable:

```
private static JSONArray jobs = null;
    ...
    ...
public static JSONArray getJobs(String url) throws JSONException {
    final JSONArray[] testArray = {null};
    RestClient.get(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            try {
                testArray[0] = response.getJSONObject("jobs").getJSONArray("values");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    return testArray[0];
```

When I call it

```
try {
  jobs = getJobs(JOBS_SEARCH_URL);
} catch (JSONException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting next error. So as I understand in some reason it didn't reach jobs variable and didn't store it there...

```
09-22 01:06:17.364  25310-25310/*my_package* E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: *my_package*, PID: 25310
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo*my_package*/*my_package*.JobsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at *my_package*.JobsActivity.getCompanyNames(JobsActivity.java:126)
            at *my_package*.JobsActivity.onCreate(JobsActivity.java:94)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2541)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2641)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**P.S.: What is a good way to store response of GET requests if `onSuccess` method is `void`?**

Comment: So I think that there is something wrong with scope in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Because the RestClient.get is async, so getJobs func can't direct return the value.

If you want do something after onSuccess.

You can like this code:

```
public static void getJobs(String url) throws JSONException {
  RestClient.get(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
      try {
        JobsActivity.jobs = response.getJSONObject("jobs").getJSONArray("values");

        //store the values.
        storeJobs(JobsActivity.jobs);

      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! What storeJobs does? I mean how  does it store value?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not a android developer. I don't know how to store the value on android system. Maybe in storeJobs you can write File or other.

Comment: public static void storeJobs(JSONArray jobs) {
     //do anything you want.
    }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61659/discussion-between-philip-and-kirill-zhukov).